# Storing Audio file using MediaStore fails on setting TITLE, ARTIST, COMPOSER etc

Tags: android, mediarecorder, mediastore, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I am using the Android MediaRecorder to create a new voice recording as an mp3 file by using the latest MediaStore Audio APIs. The properties of the new file is set using the following code.

```
val audioCollection = MediaStore.Audio.Media
        .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
val songDetails = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "sample title")
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER, "sample composer")
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "sample artist")
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting pending to 1")
        }    
val songContentUri = resolver.insert(audioCollection, songDetails)
```

But only the **DISPLAY_NAME** works, the rest all doesn't. I tried to update the file after this using the following code and that doesn't work either. Only **DISPLAY_NAME** change works. Nothing else. I don't think it is a bug on Google because most of the Media player apps should have it working. What am I missing here? Might be something silly

```
val newSongDetails = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
                Log.d(TAG, "Setting pending to 0")
                put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Jul 2 My Favorite Song.mp3")
                put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "test title")
                put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER, "test composer")
                put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "test artist")
            }

            resolver.update(it, newSongDetails, null, null)
```

Comment: `audioCollection`? Please start your post with defining that variable.

Comment: Did you managed to solve the issue?